# How to apply css to components in Next JS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I have an app in next js that is also using chakra UI. I am attempting to add a footer to the app, but am unable to force the components under the navbar to take up the remaining height of the screen.

I think my issue is that I am not correctly passing CSS styling down to the components.

`_app.tsx`

```
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <Component id='component-container' {...pageProps} />
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

`styles/globals.css`

```
#component-container {
  height: 100%
}
```

Even when I set the `#component-container` to something like `color: white` I do not see this CSS applied to the child components. I don't think I am correctly passing the CSS down to the components.

How do I correctly apply CSS to all components in next js?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass that *ID* to an HTML element inside that component...
Right now you are only passing that ID as a props to that component and probably none of the elements inside it have that ID(as I don't know what the code is for your component).
Go inside that component and either give that ID to which element you want(Probably the first DIV element) or pass it as a props to that element

Comment: Good call on the ID being passed in as props.  I think I was confused on `<Component ...`  but that must be a prop passed into MyApp by next js?

I ended up creating a layout container and wrapping `<Container..` in that layout container. There I was able to style CSS like I wanted